# How to I interleave logs from two different Oracle tables?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g

I have two log tables, which are populated from two different PL/SQL packages. It's often useful to keep the data separate, but sometimes I'd like to "interleave" the two tables so I can see what's going on in both pieces of code. Both tables have a time-stamp column (although the columns have different names). Here's a stripped-out version of the two tables, and what I'd like as a result:

Table LOG_1:

```
TIME_CREATED                  ENTRY_TEXT
-------------------------------------------
11-SEP-12 12.39.16.037824000  Log_1 entry 1
11-SEP-12 12.39.16.037824002  Log_1 entry 2
11-SEP-12 12.39.16.037824004  Log_1 entry 3
```

Table LOG_2:

```
TIME_CREATED                  ENTRY_TEXT
-------------------------------------------
11-SEP-12 12.39.16.037824001  Log_2 entry 1
11-SEP-12 12.39.16.037824003  Log_2 entry 2
11-SEP-12 12.39.16.037824005  Log_2 entry 3
```

New table LOG_COMBINED:

```
TIME                          ENTRY_TEXT
-------------------------------------------
11-SEP-12 12.39.16.037824000  Log_1 entry 1
11-SEP-12 12.39.16.037824001  Log_2 entry 1
11-SEP-12 12.39.16.037824002  Log_1 entry 2
11-SEP-12 12.39.16.037824003  Log_2 entry 2
11-SEP-12 12.39.16.037824004  Log_1 entry 3
11-SEP-12 12.39.16.037824005  Log_2 entry 3
```

(Note the [artificial] difference in the timestamps!)

I'm sure this can be done in a simple SQL statement - perhaps involving a `union all`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> select 'LOG_1' AS LOG_SOURCE, TIME_CREATED,ENTRY_TEXT 
>   FROM LOG_1
>
> UNION ALL
>
> select 'LOG_2', TIME_CREATED,ENTRY_TEXT 
>   FROM LOG_2
>
> ORDER BY 2

I formalize this kind of logic as a view so you can document and comment it.

> CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW COMBINED_LOGS
>
> (LOG_SOURCE,
>
> TIME_CREATED,
>
> ENTRY_TEXT ) AS
>
> select 'LOG_1' , TIME_CREATED,ENTRY_TEXT 
>   FROM LOG_1
>
> UNION ALL
>
> select 'LOG_2', TIME_CREATED,ENTRY_TEXT 
>   FROM LOG_2;
>
> COMMENT ON TABLE COMBINED_LOGS IS 'Explanatory comment goes here';

This works for me on Oracle 11g R2 and Oracle 9i, perhaps it was the use of keyword SOURCE as a column name which I have corrected to LOG_SOURCE

Edit: Corrected to UNION all after the comment. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all) for more discussion on the details of UNIONS.  This should be done for performance reasons and to ensure identical records are not removed.

Comment: Thanks - that works perfectly. However, Oracle (11g-R2, SQL Developer 3.2) won't let me save that as a view, because: "The SQL syntax is valid, however the query is invalid or uses functionality that is not supported. Declarative query support does not currently include UNION, INTERSECT or MINUS"

Comment: OK... actually it does let me create the view, despite that error - isn't Oracle wonderful...

Comment: I don't think it's the column name - I've also tried changing it and it reports the same error, but creates the view nonetheless.

Comment: Please do use UNION ALL, otherwise you would risk losing some rows! (as OP rightly suggested)